# can't change rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I'm having some trouble changing a rake task I made.  When I change code in the .rb file, it still runs as if I hadn't made those changes.  (eg. I add a puts to it, there is no output;  I comment out everything, it still does what it originally did.)

Do I need to reset a cache somewhere?  I've tried rebooting my machine and everything.

Here's the majority of the rake task's code:  [pastebin.com/RCgkbsPt](http://pastebin.com/RCgkbsPt)

It's run by `$  rake db:permissions`

Comment: By default there is no cache for this kind of stuff. You need to a more information like describe the structure of your files and how you run the rake tasks.

Comment: Here's a paste bin of my rake task http://pastebin.com/RCgkbsPt   The task is run by the command `$  rake db:permissions`

Comment: You can use `rake --trace db:permissions` to make sure it is running the tasks you think it is. You can also try adding the puts statement higher in the method to make sure everything is getting called

Comment: Are you running this locally in your dev environment?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, didn't know about `rake --trace db:permissions`.  I played around with the puts statement and put it at the very top and to my surprise I started seeing outputs.  It turns out I have some kind of naming conflict with the function make_roles, because changing the method name to make_roles2 leads to expected behavior.  Turned out I defined make_roles in my database population script too and since it's file name is alphabetically later, it was overwriting all of my puts statements.